# How can I make a div bounce using jquery when the webpage has been loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bounce

After a user incorrectly inputs their login details, the webpage reloads and an error message is displayed asking them to insert their details again. But I would like the error message div to bounce a few times when the page reloads after submitting the user details (or just when the page is loaded).

I came across this script that does the animation I want but requires the .click event. How could I change it so it will animate just when the page is loaded?

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
```

});

Also does this effect work with the standard jquery library?

Comment: Put it in a `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` handler instead of an element `.click()` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#my_div").effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
});
```

OR

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#my_div").effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kf3pU/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#my_div").effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
})
```